# Adodb dll versioning issue

Tags: dll, windows-7, windows-xp, adodb

I hope this question is appropriate for this site.

I've got a solution which was created in Visual Studio 2010. This solution is suppose to run on both Windows 7 and Windows XP.

The problem is that a certain project has a reference to ADODB.dll with version 6.0.0.0 which works fine on windows 7 but does not work in windows XP because there's a compilation error when trying to recognize the type `ADODB.Stream`

I noticed that the same dll with version 2.5.0.0 does seem to work on Windows XP but does not work on Windows 7... How can I solve this issue?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2517589

Comment: @HansPassant for future use.. how did you find this article? I searched google and didn't find a solution. How did you find this specific topic?

Comment: I make it my job to know these things, part of the reason my employer pays me a salary.  Answering questions at a Q+A site helps, you are not the first programmer bitten by this.

Comment: Oh master reveal your secrets :) At least so I can find a solution next time it happens without relying on others

Comment: @HansPassant It seems that the article you told me about tells me to install an update on the win 7 station, meaning I believe the article assumes that win 7 and win xp are installed on the same station but this is not the case.. they are installed on 2 different stations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end was to look at the project file in the windows XP sln, checked how the dlls are defined and copied the definitions to the Windows 7 sln. The newer sln knows how to handle the older style definitions but not the other way around so changing the new definitions to the old fixed the problem.